# Trouble with Azure Function v3 in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a set of Azure Functions, written in C#, and running on Azure Function v2 runtime (.NET Core 2.2), which work just fine.

Now I was going to create a new set of Azure Function and I want to use the v3 runtime (.NET Core 3.1). However, when "transferring" the code from my existing code base, I ran into this problem: I have a `Startup.cs` file that's setting up the Dependency Injection for the Azure Functions, and this is what it looked like in my Azure Function v2 project:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyCorp.MyProject.Infrastructure.Startup))]
namespace MyCorp.MyProject.RisWebportalService.Infrastructure
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            // more lines here, setting up DI
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to use this in the Azure Function v3 project, I get an error on the `builder.Services.AddHttpClient();` line - seems `IFunctionsHostBuilder` in v3 doesn't have this extension method anymore......

So what do I do instead? I cannot seem to find any really useful documentation on any breaking changes in Azure Function runtime between v2 and v3  - any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the package [Microsoft.Extensions.Http, version 3.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/).

The test result after installing it:

[image]

I found the same issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2847).

Comment: I did not notice till today, mine was resolved automatically when SwashBuckle package was installed for DI